# Can all NP-hard problems be reduced to one another?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard

I know that all NP-complete problems can be reduced to each other, but how about NP-hard problems? Can all NP-hard problems be reduced to one another?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the definition of P, NP, NP-complete and NP-hard?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. Take for example the $SAT$ problem and Halting problem. Both are NP- Hard but second can't be reduced to first.

Answer (score 3):

Can all NP-hard problems be reduced to one another?: **No**.

But can all NP-complete be reduced to NP-hard problems?: **Yes**

Remember: $L \text{ is NP-hard } \wedge L \in NP \rightarrow L \text{ is  NP-complete}$

And NP-hard means, all problems in NP can be reduced to one NP-hard one, but not the other way around, since not all NP-hard problems are also in NP.

---

(Update):

So not all NP-hard problems can be reduced to another, because they aren't all in NP. 
One could say basically this:

$P \subseteq NP \subseteq \text{\{decidable problems\}} \subset \text{\{decision problems\}}$

The *halting problem* e.g. is not decidable. But complexity classes like NP are saying how much time it takes to decide/verify a problem. Obviously the *halting problems* takes infinite time aka forever, so $\notin NP$. But since it is defined for **all** programs i.e. input, it could solve all problems in NP like *SAT*, so **the *halting problem* is NP-hard**. So *SAT* is reduce able to the *halting problem*. But you can't reduce the *halting problem* to *SAT*, since *SAT* is decidable (and also NP-complete), while the *halting problem* is not.

Comment: Looks much better.  By the way, you could make the inclusion between NP and the decidable problems strict: we know that there are decidable problems that aren't in NP: for example, the nondeterministic version of the time hierarchy theorem says that NEXP-complete problems can't be in NP.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Good to know. Will do as soon as I at least halfway understood the two theorems (time hierachy, and the space one) :-)